# jQuery AJAX: Get Meta-Data from Cross Domain HTML-Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, facebook-opengraph

How can I execute a ajax-call to a linked *cross-domain* HTML-page and get the content of a meta-tag of this linked page?

The goal is to get for example the URL of a OpenGraph-Image — as Facebook or Google+ are doing it — from any possible URL/Website. I deliver the URL (`decURL`) and then the script should get the og:image-URL from the metadata of this remote url/page.

The following code only works with the same domain/local — but I need it to work cross-domain, so I can enter any URL and the script will get me the og:image…

```
    $.get(decURL, function(data){
      var $ogImage = $(data).filter("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content');

      $imgPlaceholder.prepend($articleImage.attr('src',$ogImage));
      $imgField.val($ogImage);
    });
```

Comment: If the other site has not implemented CORS, you would need a server proxy

Comment: @mplungjan: the goal should be to get this working on ANY possible URL/Website

Comment: then you need a proxy. End of story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of functionality is intentionally restricted by most browsers, for security reasons (read up on [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), some of the types of attack it is intended to restrict - [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) - and ways to get around it, including [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) if you have control of both server environments).

Since you don't fall into the category where you can do things by the book, by implementing CORS etc., you have to go the long way around. Essentially, in order to be able to grab the metadata of *any* site, you'll need to do the grabbing from a server.

In this case, the server is in fact a client and therefore won't be restricted by those policies (it sounds confusing, but basically the server asks another server for the page in exactly the same way that your browser client does).

Depending what you're trying to do, you might want this as a proxy or as a separate app.

As a standalone app you'd write a simple script that runs on a server somewhere and does your scanning for you, putting the results in a DB on your own environment that your browser can access (which is more or less the way Facebook does it).

As a proxy, you'd write a similar script but instead of being triggered by something like a cron job or time-based trigger, and saving the results in a DB, it would be triggered by a request from your front end, go and grab the other page, scan the metadata and then return it to your browser client.

The main downside of this is that you're putting extra load on your server every time you ask for something, meaning you need to be careful not to overload your hosting environment. This is presumably why FB etc go down the 'server app' route.

It sounds like a pain but it's actually pretty trivial to put together, and there really isn't an alternative if you want to be able to scan anything, and not just things you make or can ask people to configure.

Comment: Thx. Just found out that you can use YQL as a hosted proxy: http://ninjagirl.com/posts/2012/02/create-facebook-style-link-preview-using-jquery-yql

Comment: That's good to know. You're now dependent on the YQL service being up and available, but it's probably pretty safe  :)  FWIW there are various other services you could potentially use in case YQL doesn't work out for you.